# How to redirect from one page to another in GWT

Tags: gwt

I want to redirect from one GWT page to another. I know one GWT module has only one .html page in war file. But is there is any way to redirect from one .html page to another GWT page in a different module.?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
Window.Location.replace(newModuleUrl)
```

Comment: I'd rather use `assign()` than `replace()`, unless you explicitly want to _break_ the user's history.

Answer (score 2):

To leave trace in the history use:

```
Window.Location.assign(newModuleUrl)
```

To do not leave recorded the current URL in the browser history use:

```
Window.Location.replace(newModuleUrl)
```

*Thanks [Thomas Broyer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/116472/thomas-broyer)*

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using this code:

```
UrlBuilder builder = Location.createUrlBuilder().setParameter(
          queryParam, value);
Window.Location.replace(builder.buildString());
```